# How to create map view like Windows Phone 7 Local Scout?

Tags: windows-phone-7

What kind of page (Pivot/Panorama) can we replicate the following? It seems to be a Panorama but with a Map control on top of it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can put any control in the title.